# Excel Formula needed that will generate a sum and percentage based on a text value in a set of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help generating a percentage.

A1 = Sum(A2:A3)

Cells A2, A3, A4 are numeric input for sum in A1

Percentage in B1 ~~Calculation needed~~

If I add a text Value in B2, generate the B1 Percentage from  related A2 number / A1 Sum

If I add a text value in B2 & B3, generate the B1 Percentage from  related A2 + A3 sum numbers / A1 sum.

This could continue for 10-20 rows. I am entering in dates into column B. If a date is present in that column I want to update the Percentage of records in B1 by getting the corresponding numbers from Column A (A1 is the total and A2 and below are all input numbers).

Can anyone help?

Comment: 1. A date is not a 'text Value'. 2. `Sum(A2:A3)` is not 'Cells A2, A3, A4'. 3. Percentage is a number divided by another number; i.e. a **ratio**. What are you dividing the sum of A:A by? 4. What's wrong with SUMIF(S) ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to specify

Comment: 1. Correct, the data entered into B2,B3...is a date format 'M/D/YYYY' and not text, 2. I should have displayed A1 as =Sum(A2:A4), 3. Ratio, correct. 4. The Sum in A2:A4 (all which apply to matching B cells) will be divided by A1 for the ratio, 5. What would the sumifs function look like in my example?

Comment: Please don't bury additional information about your problem in the comments.  Use the edit link to update your original post to make it clearer.  See [ask] and [mcve] for more tips on asking effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you won't have gaps in the B series please try:

```
=TEXT(SUM(OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(B2:B23),1))/100*A1,"#%")
```

Comment: Nice combination of a volatile function returning text-that-looks-like-a-number.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=sumifs(a2:index(a:a, match(1e99, a:a)), b2:index(b:b, match(1e99, a:a)), "<>")/sum(a2:index(a:a, match(1e99, a:a)))
```